# How can I make for loop of #define function?

Tags: c, loops, macros, c-preprocessor

I have `#define` function with argument such as `DEF_GLOBAL_STRUCT(index)` and I need to call this macro from 1 to 100. What is the best way? Can I use `for` loop?

I made the simple code to show my problem.

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>

#define DEF_GLOBAL_STRUCT(index)    uint8_t m_##index##_size=2; \
    uint32_t m_##index##_data1=0; \
    uint32_t m_##index##_data2=0;

DEF_GLOBAL_STRUCT(1)
DEF_GLOBAL_STRUCT(2)
DEF_GLOBAL_STRUCT(3)
// ...
DEF_GLOBAL_STRUCT(100)

int main()
{
    printf("%u\n", m_1_size);
    return 0;
}
```

Instead of 100 lines of define function call, can I use something like `for` loop. Or is there any other solution?

If I have all the control of the code I can define structure and declare it with array. But I can't do it. I need to use this type of define function. That is my limitation.

Comment: "_If I have all the control of the code_" Can you elaborate? Arrays seem to be the easier route...

Comment: So you need 300 global variables!? This seem to call for a redesign

Comment: BTW: The macro name suggests definition of a struct but there is no struct involved

Comment: @TrebledJ, I am using library or framework which has that type of data structure.

Comment: Are you certain the framework won't work if you use an array of arrays?

Comment: @StoryTeller, I am pretty sure I can't

Comment: @YoungminKim You are using a library that requires you to define 300 global variables with these names... really? I find that very hard to believe. My guess is that you have misunderstood how the library is to be used.

Comment: @4386427, Actually this is the CANopen object dictionary definition. Framework provides GUI tool to generate this header file. But I need to handle the header file directly without GUI tool. So it might sound weird, but there is no other option for me.

Comment: @YoungminKim Hmm... I don't know that specific framework. I find this very strange so maybe I'll find time to look into it and see why they do it like this. BTW: Would have been better if you have mentioned that specific framework as part of your question.

Comment: Look for "99 bottles of beer" --- [found it](http://99-bottles-of-beer.net/language-c-c++-preprocessor-115.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can save some typing by defining another macro:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>

#define DEF_GLOBAL_STRUCT(index)    uint8_t m_##index##_size=2; \
    uint32_t m_##index##_data1=0; \
    uint32_t m_##index##_data2=0;

#define DEF_GLOBAL_STRUCT_DECADE(tens) \
    DEF_GLOBAL_STRUCT(tens##0) \
    DEF_GLOBAL_STRUCT(tens##1) \
    DEF_GLOBAL_STRUCT(tens##2) \
    DEF_GLOBAL_STRUCT(tens##3) \
    DEF_GLOBAL_STRUCT(tens##4) \
    DEF_GLOBAL_STRUCT(tens##5) \
    DEF_GLOBAL_STRUCT(tens##6) \
    DEF_GLOBAL_STRUCT(tens##7) \
    DEF_GLOBAL_STRUCT(tens##8) \
    DEF_GLOBAL_STRUCT(tens##9)

DEF_GLOBAL_STRUCT(1)
DEF_GLOBAL_STRUCT(2)
DEF_GLOBAL_STRUCT(4)
DEF_GLOBAL_STRUCT(5)
DEF_GLOBAL_STRUCT(6)
DEF_GLOBAL_STRUCT(7)
DEF_GLOBAL_STRUCT(8)
DEF_GLOBAL_STRUCT(9)
DEF_GLOBAL_STRUCT_DECADE(1)
DEF_GLOBAL_STRUCT_DECADE(2)
DEF_GLOBAL_STRUCT_DECADE(3)
DEF_GLOBAL_STRUCT_DECADE(4)
DEF_GLOBAL_STRUCT_DECADE(5)
DEF_GLOBAL_STRUCT_DECADE(6)
DEF_GLOBAL_STRUCT_DECADE(7)
DEF_GLOBAL_STRUCT_DECADE(8)
DEF_GLOBAL_STRUCT_DECADE(9)
DEF_GLOBAL_STRUCT(100)

int main()
{
    printf("%u\n", m_1_size);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I like your idea. :-)

Answer (score 6):

Your question is asking if you can mix C language with Preprocessor directives to automate the generation of code using both C language and Preprocessor directives.

The answer is not in the way you are trying to do it because of how the Preprocessor and the C compiler work.

The Preprocessor is a separate step from compilation. The idea is that the Preprocessor does a text replacement step of the C source code file to generate a new, temporary version of the C source code file which is then compiled by the C compiler.

It is two different steps and first the Preprocessor does its work and then the C compiler does its work.

What I would suggest is to write a simple program that generates an include file that contains the list of definitions you want to use. Then in the place where you want to put those definitions, use the #include directive to include it at that point.

So if you have a simple script or perhaps a C program something like:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main ()
{
    int i;
    for (i = 1; i <= 100; i++) printf ("DEF_GLOBAL_STRUCT(%d)\n", i);

    return 0;
}
```

Then you compile it and run it from a command line redirecting the output as in:

```
mygen >junk.h
```

then in the place you need these directives:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>

#define DEF_GLOBAL_STRUCT(index)    uint8_t m_##index##_size=2; \
    uint32_t m_##index##_data1=0; \
    uint32_t m_##index##_data2=0;

#include "junk.h"

int main()
{
    printf("%u\n", m_1_size);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: If a little program is used for generating an include file, why keep on using macros? I would let the program do the expansion as well.

Comment: @4386427 since the macro definition is in the source file while the macro usage is in the include file, should the macro definition change (so long as the parameters do not change), the include file is still good.

Comment: I don't see the difference between changing the macro-definition or changing the help program.

Comment: @4386427 depends on your source code control and how you want to do it.